# TFS Gated build and running tests

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, mstest, tfsbuild

I recently realized that not all of my tests are being run in the build server. On the TFS Build config I have set to run all dlls and check for folders recursively.

Test Sources Spec:     `**\**.dll`

I want to TFS build output folder and it seems all the libraries that has test are there. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
I would like to know why it is not firing all my tests?

**UPDATE:**
Here is my build settings.
[image]

Comment: Should I say Hi or Thanks?! The answer is no: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @jessehouwing No I am not using any third party test framework. Everything is MSTest.

Comment: Try setting the pattern to `**\*.dll`, notice the removed extra `*`

Comment: `**` doesn't make sense for the filename, `**\ ` is the key to search recursively, `*.dll` is the format for any file that ends with `.dll`.

Comment: @jessehouwing I changed it to as you suggested (that how it was before) and running the build. See if there is any difference.

Comment: @jessehouwing No luck with changing the Test Sources Spec to as you suggested

Comment: Maybe weird question, but is "Disable Tests"  set to true? Or is a Test Filter configured? Can you post a screenshots of the build definition and the log?

Comment: And the log? Us there a specific reason to set the test platform to x86 instead of auto?

Comment: I looked at build log and has nothing about tests are not being fired. Currently the platform is set to x86 and I think it is default. I wasn't able to set it to Auto. There is no option. Sorry for the security purposes I can't post the log.

Comment: I don't see any reasons why the tests would not run. Have you tried running them from the commandline on your build server? Is Visual Studio installed on the build server?